# Get all row values from single column

Tags: python, pandas

This code is working and retrieving the exact data i need. I just need to output all the row values into a single value;

HERE IS THE bit of CODE

```
dfs = pd.read_html(str(tables))
df =  dfs[0].iloc[[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19],[1]]
s = df['score'].str.split('-',expand=True).astype(int)
df['team_win'] = np.where(s[0] == s[1], 0,s.idxmax(1) + 1)
df = df['team_win'].drop([9, 11])
```

HERE IS THE OUTPUT

```
Name: team_win, dtype: int64
1     1
3     0
5     2
7     0
13    1
15    2
17    2
19    2
```

I need the team_win to be outputed like this... 10201222  so i can copy into google sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranked from best performance to worst performance, you could:

**1)**

```
''.join(map(str, df['team_win']))
Out[319]: '10201222'
```

**2)**

```
''.join(df['team_win'].map(str))
Out[320]: '10201222'
```

**3)**

```
''.join([str(i) for i in df['team_win']])
Out[313]: '10201222'
```

Thanks to @piRSquared for the additional suggestions

Comment: `''.join(map(str, so['team_win']))` OR `''.join(so['team_win'].map(str))`

Comment: Is it better, in this case, to use ```map``` instead of a list comprehension?  Could you also please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, confirmed for `1_000_000` length series, `map` was best followed by `.map` then comprehension. 258 ms, 297 ms, 324 ms respectively.  ***TO BE CLEAR*** To Readers/OP These are trivial differences.  The comprehension answer is JUST FINE!

Comment: Well, i cant get it to work... would be happy if you can just  show me where to add this to to code to work.... i seriously dont know how to add your code... thanks

Comment: ```so``` is just the way I named the dataframe on my console.

Comment: Am I suppose to add your code like this?    ss = ''.join([str(i) for i in df['team_win']]) I get errors       raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'team_win'

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: Didnt work... get errors  lss = ''.join([str(i) for i in df['team_win']]>>>>>File "\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 853, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key) >>>  File pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'team_win'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230424/discussion-between-sophocles-and-raving-sonofcodes).